# SharePoint Online, possible way to track user activity?

Tags: android-activity, sharepoint

I'm currently working on a SharePoint and I'm looking to implement a page that tracks which user read which document/ viewed a file.

Would I need to use Powershell or is there a plugin app on the SharePoint store?

Answer (score 0):

Users' activities in SharePoint Online is a part of Office 365. The first step you need to do is to enable Audit Logs feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance.

Then you can retrieve audit logs by using Microsoft Graph API (it's not Powershell script but hopefully you can find some ideas from it): https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/01/18/retrieve-office-365-audit-logs-using-office-management-api-and-azure-functions/